# Command line arguments not working. Logic error of some sort

Tags: c, command-line, getopt

I'm having problems getting my command-line arguments to work properly. The arguments appear to fail when the `argc` is higher than 3 and after that you can only get them to work if you write *-fwhatever* and not *-f whatever* as it should be. -t also copies the value of -o.

```
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    int c;

    /* Are we in root? */

    if(geteuid() !=0)
        {
            printf("Root access is required to run this program. \n");

            exit(0);        
        }   

    /* How do we use the program */

    if ((argc < 6) || (argc > 8))
        {
            usage(argv[0]);

            exit (0);
        } 

    while (1)
        {
            static struct option long_options[] =
                {
                    /* Options */
                {"send",       no_argument,       0, 's'},
                {"recieve",    no_argument,       0, 'r'},
                {"file",       required_argument, 0, 'f'},
                {"data",       required_argument, 0, 'd'},
                {"destip",     required_argument, 0, 'i'},
                {"destport",   required_argument, 0, 'p'},
                {"sourceip",   required_argument, 0, 'o'},
                {"sourceport", required_argument, 0, 't'},
                {0, 0, 0, 0}
                };

               int option_index = 0;

               c = getopt_long (argc, argv, "srf:d:i:p:o:t:",
                            long_options, &option_index);

                          /* Detect the end of the options. */
               if (c == -1)
                 break;

               switch (c)
                 {
                 case 0:
                   /* If this option set a flag, do nothing else now. */
                   if (long_options[option_index].flag != 0)
                 break;
                   printf ("option %s", long_options[option_index].name);
                   if (optarg)
                 printf (" with arg %s", optarg);
                   printf ("\n");
                   break;

                 case 's':
                   puts ("option -s\n");
                   break;

                 case 'r':
                   puts ("option -r\n");
                   break;

                 case 'f':
                   printf ("option -f with value `%s'\n", optarg);
                   break;

                 case 'd':
                   printf ("option -d with value `%s'\n", optarg);
                   break;

                 case 'i':
                   printf ("option -i with value `%s'\n", optarg);
                   break;

                 case 'p':
                   printf ("option -p with value `%s'\n", optarg);
                   break;

                 case 'o': 
                   printf ("option -o with value `%s'\n", optarg);

                 case 't': 
                   printf ("option -t with value `%s'\n", optarg);


                 case '?':
                   /* Error message printed */
                   break;

                 default:
                   abort ();
                 }
             }

               /* Print any remaining command line arguments (not options). */
            if (optind < argc)
        {
            printf ("non-option ARGV-elements: ");
            while (optind < argc)
            printf ("%s ", argv[optind++]);
            putchar ('\n');
        }

        getchar ();
        exit (0);

}
```

There's obviously something horribly wrong here, but it can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the -o copied to -t, you forgot to put a `break;` at the end of the case.

Also, I would have removed the `argc` checking. Let `getopt` do its magic. You can check at the end of parsing if all mandatory options were set. You can also check for unknown arguments.

Comment: how many times i used to tear my hair out for same kind of problems! compilers should stop compiling this stuff. or a second switch construct. which will compile without breaks at each case. but switch proper will not compile.

Comment: Thanks @eyalm! it's so easy to miss stuff like that. Any suggestions on what the best way of checking for mandatory options?

Comment: Just set all the option variables to NULL. After running getopt, make sure they were all initialized.